Inequality of Entire functions
Suppose $f$ is an entire function.
Question: Does this inequality always hold?
$$|f(z)| \leq \left|\int_{\gamma}f(z) \; dz \right|, \quad \forall z \in \mathbb C. $$
Trivially this would hold if $f(z)$ is identically $0$ also if $\gamma$  is a closed contour and $f$ is entire (and thus holomorphic everywhere), by Cauchy's integral theorem, $\int_{\gamma} f(z) \, dz = 0 $ for any closed path $\gamma$. This would make the right-hand side of the inequality zero, invalidating the inequality for any $z$  where $ f(z) \neq 0 $.
If not, under what conditions would it hold? Thank you so much in advance; any help and hints would be greatly appreciated!

Why do you expect such an inequality? Is there an inequality of the type $|f(x)| \leq |\int_a^{b} f(y) dy|$ in the real case?

You have$$\cos\left(\frac\pi2\right)=1\quad\text{and}\quad\int_\gamma\cos(z)\,\mathrm dz=0$$if $\gamma\colon\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ is the path defined by $\gamma(t)=t$.
More generally, that inequality is false for every entire function other than the null function. In fact, if $z_0\in\Bbb C$ is such that $f(z_0)\ne0$ and if $\gamma$ is the constant path $z_0$, then $\bigl|\int_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm dz\bigr|=0<|f(z_0)|$.
